# Midi and interface connectivity question

Tags: recording, midi-controller-keyboard, homerecording, computer

I own a MacBook Pro with 2 USB ports. I have it connected to an external monitor and have its lid off below the base the monitor sits on. To it I connect my Scarlett Solo 2 Audio Interface on one USB port and my keyboard to the other.

This config is ok when I want to connect a mic or a guitar on the Audio Interface but I do have a problem when I want to connect my midi keyboard (which takes power from the USB port). Then I have to unplug my keyboard to use my midi controller but this makes Logic Pro X (or other DAWs) less functional.

I want to ask what other people do to in similar situations. I assume I need a USB hub with external power supply (i.e. to plug it into power directly) but I am not sure if this is safe for the computer/controller.

Any ideas? I assume people have similar issues with the newer MacBook Pros.

Answer (score 2):

A powered USB hub will not harm anything when used in the perfectly normal manner you describe.

Comment: If you can do so, try the USB hub before you buy. Not everything works when connected together without some hassle.